# .NET 7 appsettings.json based on solution configuration

Tags: configuration, appsettings, .net-7.0

Is possible to load appsettings based on active solution configuration? Something like - when I select debug so appsettings.Development.json is used.

For example:

I have active solution configuration named "MyCustomConfig" and I want the "appsettings.MyCustomConfig.json" setting to be used.

I found only solutions which used launch settings, but it's not what I want..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of googling... I tryed put "$(ConfigurationName)" variable to launchsettings.json to:

```
"environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "$(ConfigurationName)"
  }
```

and it worked. I thinked there is no way to put it here.